# Trying to compare characters in shell script but I'm getting an error

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, sh, string-comparison

Why isn't this if-else operation working? I fixed my spacing many times yet getting the error **syntax error near unexpected token `elif'** , I have tried using "==" instead of "=", I have tried using two third brackets but nothing seems to work.

```
if [ "$operation" = "+" ]
  then addition()
elif [ "$operation" = "-" ]
  then subtraction()
elif [ "$operation" = "*" ]
  then multiplication()
elif [ "$operation" = "/" ]
  then division()
fi
```

---

Comment: It seems to be the way you call functions. You don't need the `()`.

Comment: This looks so much like a hybrid of shell and Python that I couldn't see anything wrong at first :)

Answer (score 3):

You should remove parantheses to call the function. Whenever you encounter syntax issues like this, please use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) website to identify what's wrong.

```sh
if [ "$operation" = "+" ]
  then addition
elif [ "$operation" = "-" ]
  then subtraction
elif [ "$operation" = "*" ]
  then multiplication
elif [ "$operation" = "/" ]
  then division
fi
```